# UWP C#: Returning to ContentDialog from Page

Tags: c#, uwp

I have navigated from a `ContentDialog` to a `Page` in my UWP app written in C#. Now I want to return back to the `ContentDialog` when I click a button on the `Page`.

I tried writing `(Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.GoBack();` but that only returned to my `MainPage` (from where my `ContentDialog` was launched).

If it is possible to perform such an action, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: No, you can't do this. You were not navigating from content dialog, but from some page. Content dialog was just a control used to call the navigate to next page action. If you want to go back and see the dialog, navigate back and show the dialog again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not navigate **to** or even **from** content dialog. What you do is that you are navigating between the pages. Action that you call in your dialog does invoke this navigation i.e. there would be no difference if it was done with button or button in content dialog - these are just controls on your page.

If you want to see the dialog on MainPage when you navigate back, implement the logic to show it again if certain conditions are met (for example pass NavigationEventArgs containing details whether Content Dialog should be re-opened).